# COM object that has been separated from its underlying RCW cannot be used while testing

Tags: c#, .net, com, singleton

I'm doing some test using the .NET 4.5 TestTools and Visual Studio 2010. I m testing a singleton class that creates an COM Instance somewhere during construction/initialization, so the classes state will be keep the same in all tests. The Problem is, each test runs for itself, running all test will give a strange result - the first test succeeds, all other fail

> "System.Runtime.InteropServices.InvalidComObjectException: COM object
>   that has been separated from its underlying RCW cannot be used.."

result of a corrupted COM reference (see myComInstance below).

Not quite sure if i explained the problem correctly. Below is my singleton class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace APITestTrial3
{
    public  partial class  frmMbxControl : Form
    {
        private frmMbxControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Connect("abhishek281mbx","PCMBXsrv.281","appmat1.bsd.com");

        }

        private static frmMbxControl g_Mbx;

        public static frmMbxControl GetMbx()
        {
            if (g_Mbx == null)
            {
                g_Mbx = new frmMbxControl();
            }

            return g_Mbx;
        }

        private string Connect(string mbxName, string serverName, string hostName)
        {
            //  frmControls frm = new frmControls();
            mbx.HostName = hostName;
            mbx.MbxName = mbxName;
            mbx.ServerName = serverName;
            mbx.replybox = "replyBox";

            if (mbx.Status != 0)
            {
                if (mbx.Connect())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Connected");
                    return ("Connected");
                }
                else
                {
                    return ("Not Connected");
                }
            }
            return ("Connected");
        }



        public String Send(String txnName, String txn)
        {
            String msgReply = "";
            String rep = "";
            //mbx.Send(txnName, txn);
            mbx.Open("ReplyBox1","c");
            mbx.SendAndReply(txnName, txn, "ReplyBox1");

            if (mbx.WaitForMsg("ReplyBox1", 0, ref msgReply, ref rep) == CwMboxLib.CwWaitResult.CwWaitOk)
            {

                rep = msgReply;
                mbx.Close("ReplyBox1");
            }

            return msgReply;
        }

        private void frmMbxControl_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Another class  uses GetMbx() and Send() method of above class.

Comment: At which line does the error occur?

Comment: Something performed a garbage collection of the COM object. This can be a call to `Marshall.ReleaseCOMObject` (or similar) or a .NET initiated garbage collection. Are you sure your singleton is a true singleton class?

Comment: It happens when another class tries to access Send method. There are two methods in another class which calls Send method as GetMbx().Send().

Comment: I think you should rewrite your singleton class and don't put it in the `Form` class. Examples are all over the web. Here is one: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx